# Defining a variable in Dart/Flutter and referencing parent context

Tags: dart, flutter

Suppose I have an AppBar:

```
final AppBar myAppBar = AppBar(
  leading: IconButton(
    icon: Icon(Icons.delete),
    onPressed: () {},
  ),
);
```

If I want to reference the main parent context in that `onPressed` function, is there a way to reference the variable without creating a new class or creating a function which takes the context as an argument for constructing a new component?

```
final AppBar myAppBar = AppBar(
  leading: IconButton(
    icon: Icon(Icons.delete),
    onPressed: () { print(this.context); },
  ),
);
```

Comment: What do you mean by `main parent context`? Do you want to reference the context of the parent `Widget`?

Comment: @HugoPassos Yes. I have a `main.dart` file with a MaterialApp. I'd like to see what it's like using an AppBar variable rather than directly composing it into the Scaffold. But, this AppBar would need to reference it's parent context from that main file to perform one of the functions.

Comment: I think I have a solution for this, but I'm not so sure if it fits in your code. Can you please share a minimal reproduction of what you currently have?

Comment: @HugoPassos Here's my initial, naive approach https://github.com/iRyanBell/learning-how-to-flutter_gsdist-part-2/blob/master/lib/utils.dart Shortly after that, I rewrote it using an OOP model: https://github.com/iRyanBell/learning-how-to-flutter_gsdist-part-3/blob/master/lib/icon_button.dart But I really don't like the feel of that when I imagine a much bigger project.

Comment: Have you tried passing the parent `BuildContext` to the child?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You said the parent `Widget` was a `MaterialApp`, so in order to access the `BuildContext` of a parent `Widget`, you can use the `BuildContext` of the child `Widget` in the following way:

```dart
class Foo extends StatefulWidget {
  ...
}

class FooState extends State<Foo> {
  ...

  BuildContext getParentContext() {
    return context.ancestorStateOfType(const TypeMatcher<MaterialApp>()).context;
  }
}
```

If you don't have access to the child's `BuildContext`, then you have 2 other options:

1. Passing a callback which gives the parent's `BuildContext` when the child requires it:

```dart
class FooParent extends StatelessWidget {
  ...

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Foo(onProvideParentContext: () => context);
  }
}

typedef ContextProvider = BuildContext Function();

class Foo extends StatefulWidget {
  final ContextProvider onProvideParentContext;

  Foo({
    @required this.onProvideParentContext,
  });

  ...
}

class FooState extends State<Foo> {
  ...

  BuildContext getParentContext() {
    return widget.onProvideParentContext();
  }
}
```

2. Passing the `BuildContext` directly to the child as a parameter.

```dart
class FooParent extends StatelessWidget {
  ...

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Foo(parentContext: context);
  }
}

class Foo extends StatefulWidget {
  final BuildContext parentContext;

  Foo({
    @required this.parentContext,
  });

  ...
}

class FooState extends State<Foo> {
  ...

  BuildContext getParentContext() {
    return widget.parentContext;
  }
}
```

Comment: That looks like it would do the trick. But ideally, I'm looking for a solution without extended classes.

Answer (score 0):

After some digging, I came across `Builder` and `StatefulBuilder` in the Flutter API documentation:

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Builder-class.html
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StatefulBuilder-class.html

```
final AppBar myAppBar = AppBar(
  leading: IconButton(
    icon: Icon(Icons.delete),
    onPressed: () { print(this.context); },
  ),
);
```

Would become:

```
final AppBar myAppBar = AppBar(
  leading: Builder(
    builder: (BuildContext context) => IconButton(
      icon: Icon(Icons.delete),
      onPressed: () { print(context); },
    ),
  ),
);
```

or, if I need state:

```
int totalClicks = 0;

final PreferredSizeWidget myAppBar = PreferredSize(
  preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(50.0),
  child: StatefulBuilder(
    builder: (
      BuildContext context,
      StateSetter setState,
    ) {
      return AppBar(
        leading: IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.thumb_up),
          onPressed: () => setState(() => totalClicks++),
        ),
        title: Text('Clicked: $totalClicks times!')
      );
    }
  ),
);
```